# In Kotlin, How does the following code snippet work to swap variables values?

Tags: android, kotlin

```
    fun main() {
    var a = 1
    var b = 2
    a = b.also { b = a }
    println("Values after swap a = $a and b = $b")
    }
```

I am trying to understand how this function works to swap the variables? I have been debugging this code but not able to get how this is executed.

Does anybody make me understand the execution of the same code?, Thanks in adavance

Answer (score 4):

In a way you can read

```
variable.also{ codeblock }
```

as

1. read the `variable` and store it in a temporary variable
2. execute the `codeblock`
3. return what you stored in step 1.

So in your case it's

1. read `b` (which has value `2`) and store it in a temporary variable
2. execute the `b = a`. meaning that `1` is assigned to the variable `b`.
3. return what you stored in step 1, which is the value `2`.
4. this value is then assigned to the variable `a`

Comment: by the way,  maybe your initial confusion came from you interpreting the code as `(a = b).also { b = a }` but it really is `a = (b.also { b = a })`

Comment: I have been thinking in this way but didn't find any documentation or anything where this flow is explained

Comment: @Janki Maybe it would be cleaner for you if you rewrite this to: `a = also(b, { b = a })`. `b` is just an argument we pass to the `also` function. And in Java/Kotlin, arguments are passed by copy. After `also` invokes the lambda, it returns the same argument we passed to it and only then we can assign its result to `a`. So this specific case is not documented anywhere, because it is a matter of more general rules like passing arguments by copy or that the `also` is simply a function we call passing the receiver and the lambda to it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the documentation of [`also`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/also.html):

> ```kotlin
> inline fun <T> T.also(block: (T) -> Unit): T
> ```
>
> Calls the specified function `block` with `this` value as its argument and returns `this` value.

From that, we can note the following things:

1. It is an [extension function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/extensions.html#extension-functions) (thus has a receiver).
2. It is an [inline function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/inline-functions.html).
3. Its argument is a [function type](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#function-types), which:

   - Accepts the receiver as an argument.
   - Will also be inlined.
4. It returns the receiver object.

That all means this:

```kotlin
fun swapDemo() {
    var a = 42
    var b = 117
    a = b.also { b = a }
}
```

Is approximately the same as writing this:

```kotlin
fun swapDemo() {
    var a = 42
    var b = 117

    // begin 'also'
    val receiver = b
    val it = receiver // the 'block' function's parameter (unused)
    b = a // the 'block' function
    // end 'also'

    a = receiver // 'also' "returns"
}
```

Ignoring the `it` variable (also see below), you can see this looks just like a "traditional" swap implementation, with `receiver` functioning as the temporary variable.

---

Note that, from inspecting the byte code, writing the following:

```kotlin
a = b.also { _ -> b = a }
```

Instead of:

```kotlin
a = b.also { b = a }
```

Will cause the `it` local variable to be omitted. At least in Kotlin 1.9.22.